# How do I link an Excel Check Box (ActiveX Control) to a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

Linking an Excel Check Box (Form Control) to a cell is easy:

1) Add a Check Box.
2) Select the Check Box (I normally right-click it).
3) In the Formula Bar, type "=".
4) Click the cell I want to link to and press Enter.

What this does is make the cell show "TRUE" if I check the Check Box, and "FALSE" if I uncheck it. Does anyone know how to do this for a Check Box (ActiveX Control)?

Comment: By using the "Linked Cell" poperty

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It works!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the check box, select properties, and look for "LinkedCell"